# How to call java method in JSTL?

Tags: java, jstl, method-call

This might be duplicate question.

I just want to call method which is not getter or setter method **eg. makeCall(someObj,"stringvalue") of xyz class.**

Java Class

```
Class XYZ{

    public String makeCall(Object objValue, String stringValue){

    //some logic here

    }
}
```

JSTL

```
<jsp:userBean id="xyz" class="com.XYZ"/>
${xyz.makeCall("hello","Friend")}
```

Comment: but it return list. How can I get that returned string?

Comment: Just a small typo correction. It is 'useBean' and not 'userBean'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolve this we need create your own tag. (in .tld file)

and need to write one java class for this tag.

After this you can call method within that your own class and set result to pageCotext to retrive it on jsp.

Answer (score 5):

Simply create an object of the class using `<jsp:useBean>` and call the method using [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) that is more easy to use and less error prone.

sample code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="com.x.y.z.XYZ"/>

${test.methodXYZ(object,"myString")}
```

Read more about [Implicit Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) that might help you.

Comment: It gives me unable to parse EL function error..

Comment: Please share what have you tried. Edit it in your actual question. How are you passing the object?

Comment: what is `<jsp:userBean` it should be `<jsp:useBean`

Comment: Actually I have string in that place. I have edited question please check it

Comment: have you changed `user` to `use`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
<c:out value="${XYZbean.makeCall(someObjBean, 'value')}" />
```